# Not getting the Multithreaading to work for GTK 3 python

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3

I am trying to get the themes from the gnome-look.org and trying to create widgets by scraping the website.

I wanted to show the window first while updating the GtkWidgets necessary in the background via another Thread.

Here is my code

[code]
#!/usr/bin/python3

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, GdkPixbuf
import requests
import sys
import gi
import shutil
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import dryscrape
import json
import urllib.parse
import concurrent.futures
import threading

class ReadGnomeLook:
    def format_bytes(self, size):
        # 2**10 = 1024
        power = 2**10
        n = 0
        power_labels = {0 : '', 1: 'KB', 2: 'MB', 3: 'GB'}
        while size > power:
            size /= power
            n += 1
        return str("{:.2f}".format(size)) +' ' + str(power_labels[n])


    def getDownloadLinks(self, childURL):
        #childURL = "https://www.gnome-look.org/s/Gnome/p/1519633"
        childURL = childURL+"#files-panel"
        session = dryscrape.Session()
        session.set_attribute('auto_load_images', False)
        session.visit(childURL)
        response = session.body()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response, features='lxml')
        downloadlink = []
        allscripts = soup.find_all('script', {"src":False})
        for each_script in range(len(allscripts)):
            content = str(allscripts[each_script]).split("var")
            for indx in content:
                if 'filesJson' in str(indx):
                    content = indx.replace('filesJson = ','').replace(';','')
                    content = json.loads(content)
                    links = []
                    for each_item in content:
                        if each_item['active'] == '1':
                            links.append({'name':each_item['name'],'type':each_item['type'],'size':format_bytes(int(each_item['size'])),'md5sum':each_item['md5sum'],'title':each_item['title'],'description':each_item['description'],'url':urllib.parse.unquote(each_item['url'])})
                    for each in links:
                        downloadlink.append(each)
        return downloadlink

    def readWebpage(self, URL):

        myProducts = []
        baseURL="https://www.gnome-look.org"
        #URL = "https://www.gnome-look.org/browse/cat/132/order/latest/"
        session = dryscrape.Session()
        session.set_header('Host','www.gnome-look.org')
        session.visit(URL)
        response = session.body()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response, features='lxml')
        #print(soup)
        #soup.find(class="product-browse-item-info")
        mydivs = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "product-browse-item picture"})
        for mydiv in mydivs:
            myProducts.append([
                {'name' : mydiv.div.a.findAll("div",{"class":"product-browse-item-info"})[0].h2.text},
                {'category' : mydiv.div.a.findAll("div",{"class":"product-browse-item-info"})[0].findAll("span")[0].text},
                {'author' : mydiv.div.a.findAll("div",{"class":"product-browse-item-info"})[0].findAll("span")[1].b.text},
                {'img' : mydiv.div.a.div.img['src']},
                {'href' : mydiv.div.a['href']}
            ])
        productCatalog = []
        for elements in  myProducts:
            productCatalog.append([
                {
                    'Name':elements[0]['name'],
                    'Category': elements[1]['category'],
                    'Author': elements[2]['author'],
                    'Image': elements[3]['img'],
                    'Link': baseURL +  elements[4]['href'],
                    #'DownloadLinks': getDownloadLinks(baseURL +  elements[4]['href'])
                }
                ])
        return productCatalog

class AppicationWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):

        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Themes Manager")
       
       # Main Application Window
        # self.set_title("Themes Manager v1.0")
        #self.set_default_size(400, 400)
        self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
        self.connect("destroy",Gtk.main_quit)

        # Create Image and Title Grid
        #self.image = self.getImageFromWeb('https://media.wired.com/photos/592697678d4ebc5ab806acf7/master/w_2560%2Cc_limit/GooglePlay.jpg')
        #self.image.set_from_file("android-download.png")
        #image.set_size(200,200)
        print("Before 1st Show all")
        self.show_all()
        z = threading.Thread(target=self.doProcessing(),daemon=True)
        z.start()
        print("Started Z thread")


    def doProcessing(self):
        # Grid for Full Icon Themes
        self.gridfulliconthemes = Gtk.FlowBox(valign = Gtk.Align.START)
        self.gridfulliconthemesscroll = Gtk.ScrolledWindow(hexpand=True, vexpand=True)    # Create scroll window
        self.gridfulliconthemesscroll.add(self.gridfulliconthemes)       # Adds the TreeView to the scroll container

        self.getProductCatalog()



        ## Start
        self.URLs = []
        self.labels = []
        self.images = []
        self.threads = []

        for each_item in self.productCatalog:
            image = Gtk.Image()
            image.new_from_file('/tmp/82682596e6c89475b2f21221d5dc61927887.png')
            self.images.append(image)
            self.labels.append(Gtk.Label("loading"))

        for each_item in range(0,len(self.productCatalog)):
            #print(each_item[0]['Name'])
            self.URLs.append(self.productCatalog[each_item][0]['Image'])

            vertical_box = Gtk.Box()
            vertical_box.set_homogeneous(True)
            vertical_items = Gtk.FlowBox(valign = Gtk.Align.START)
            vertical_items.set_max_children_per_line(1)

            label = Gtk.Label()
            label.set_text(self.productCatalog[each_item][0]['Name'])
            label.set_line_wrap(True)
            label.set_max_width_chars(10)
            label.set_hexpand(True)
            self.labels.append(label)

            #image = Gtk.Image()
            #self.images.append(image)

            vertical_items.add(self.images[each_item])
            vertical_items.add(self.labels[each_item])

            vertical_box.add(vertical_items)

            vertical_box.connect("button-press-event", self.do_anything)

            self.gridfulliconthemes.add(vertical_box)

        ## End
        

        # Create Notebook to add to the Window
        self.notebook = Gtk.Notebook()
        self.add(self.notebook)

        self.fullicontheme = Gtk.Label()
        self.fullicontheme.set_text("Full Icon Themes")
        self.gtkthemes = Gtk.Label()
        self.gtkthemes.set_text("Gtk 3/4 Themes")
        self.gnomeshellthemes = Gtk.Label()
        self.gnomeshellthemes.set_text("Gnome Shell Themes")

        self.fulliconthemepage = Gtk.Label()
        self.fulliconthemepage.set_text("Full Icon Themes Page")
        self.gtkthemespage = Gtk.Label()
        self.gtkthemespage.set_text("GTK themes Page")
        self.gnomeshellthemespage = Gtk.Label()
        self.gnomeshellthemespage.set_text("Gnome Shell Themes Page")

        #notebook.append_page(fullicontheme, Gtk.Label("Icon Page"))
        self.notebook.append_page(self.gridfulliconthemesscroll, self.fulliconthemepage)
        self.notebook.append_page(self.gtkthemes, self.gtkthemespage)
        self.notebook.append_page(self.gnomeshellthemes, self.gnomeshellthemespage)
        self.notebook.set_tab_reorderable(self.gridfulliconthemesscroll, True)
        #self.add(hb)
        
        #self.show_all()

        #threadtemp = threading.Thread(target=self.getImageFromWeb(each_item[0]['Image']))
        #self.threads.append(threadtemp)

        #self.getAllImages()
        x = threading.Thread(target=self.getAllImages(),daemon=True)
        x.start()
        self.show_all()

    def getProductCatalog(self):
        # Download Links from GnomeLook.org
        URL = "https://www.gnome-look.org/s/Gnome/browse/cat/132/page/2/ord/latest/"
        readgnomelook = ReadGnomeLook()
        self.productCatalog = readgnomelook.readWebpage(URL)
        #print(json.dumps(productCatalog, sort_keys=False, indent=4))

    def getAllImages(self):
        for i in range(0,len(self.productCatalog)):
            #self.images.append(self.getImageFromWeb(self.productCatalog[i][0]['Image']))
            #self.images[i] = self.getImageFromWeb(self.productCatalog[i][0]['Image'],self.images[i])
             with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as executor:
                 future = executor.submit(self.getImageFromWeb, self.productCatalog[i][0]['Image'], self.images[i])
            #     #self.images.append(future.result())
                 self.images[i]= future.result()
            #     #print(type(self.images[i]))

    def do_anything(self):
        print("clicked on box")

    def getImageFromWeb(self, URL,image):
        filename = '/tmp/'+URL.split("/")[-1]

        try:
            f = open(filename)
            pixbuf = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file_at_scale(
                    filename=filename, 
                    width=100, 
                    height=100, 
                    preserve_aspect_ratio=False)

            Gtk.Image.set_from_pixbuf(image, pixbuf)
            #image.set_from_file(filename)
            #print("Got the image : " + filename)
            #del r
            return image
        except IOError:
            #print("File not accessible")
            r = requests.get(URL,stream=True)
            if r.status_code == 200:
                with open(filename,'wb') as f:
                    r.raw.decode_content = True
                    shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)

                pixbuf = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file_at_scale(
                        filename=filename, 
                        width=200, 
                        height=200, 
                        preserve_aspect_ratio=False)

                Gtk.Image.set_from_pixbuf(image, pixbuf)
                #image.set_from_file(filename)
                #print("Got the image : " + filename)
                return image
            else:
                #print("Failed to get the image : " + filename)
                return None
            del r


window = AppicationWindow()
#window.connect("destroy",Gtk.main_quit)
#window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
[/code]

Code works fine. But in below code, the thread doProcessing() is getting completed and then I am seeing the "Started Z thread"


    print("Before 1st Show all")
    self.show_all()
    z = threading.Thread(target=self.doProcessing(),daemon=True)
    z.start()
    print("Started Z thread")
```

As I see, doProcessing should start in background and "Started Z thread" should be printed immediately but that's not happening.

Am I missing anything here ? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks, Debasish

Answer (score 0):

```
z = threading.Thread(target=self.doProcessing(),daemon=True)
```

threading.Thread wants a function not the result of a function, thus try:

```
z = threading.Thread(target=self.doProcessing,daemon=True)
```